# Before committing my code in svn. I have mistakenly ran `svn update` in my repository and all my code is gone .. How can i revert it?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Before committing my code.. I mistakenly ran `svn update`. And then all my changes are removed and updated to new one .. I thought svn will also work like git.. But unfortunately now all my local uncommitted changes are gone repos updated.. How can i revert it ?? Is it possible .. I have lots of changes made in my local.. now i am thinking how to get it back ??

I tried a simple `svn revert` but that didn't work... As i have also changed some folder structure which didn't reverted at all .. not sure what to do now ?

Comment: Subversion does work like git in the respect that it will not overwrite local changes. Running `svn update` **will not** undo local changes. So something else must have happened. If you did changes to directory structure you would have to use `svn move` so subversion knows you moved a file and can track its changes. Could that be the issue? Don't run random commands or you will lose your changes.

Comment: On the other hand, `svn revert` will undo your changes. So if you're lucky you can salvage the files you copied around. Overall, it's unclear what you did and how you got yourself into this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Running `svn update` never removes your local modifications. But if you some  way or another removed your local modifications they are unfortunately gone. Subversion doesn't automatically backup local uncommitted changes.